# How to write a query which fetches data from a table without the quotes and double quotes in the data stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want write a simple query which will fetch data from a table (which may contain quotes and double quotes) but it should remove all the quotes in it.

e.g. for the following data:

```
EmpID  EmpName  CompName
-----  -------  -----------
1234   "xyz"    A's Company
```

Output Should Be:

```
EmpID  EmpName  CompName
-----  -------  -----------
1234   xyz      As Company
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of replace function of sql server resolve the issue for you

[REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
select EmpID,
         replace(replace(EmpName,'"', ''),'''','') Empname, 
          replace(replace(CompName,'"', ''),'''','') CompName 
from table
```

**Note:**

ordinarily you'd replace ' with '' and this will make SQL happy when querying the database. The trick with any of the built-in SQL functions (like replace) is that they too require you to double up your single quotes.

So to replace ' with '' in code you'd do this

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT EmpID, 
      EmpName, 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(CompName, '"', ''), '''','') 
  FROM dbo.table;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select
    EmpID,
    replace(EmpName, '"', '') as EmpName,
    CompName
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to replace single/double quotes in both the EmpName and CompName columns.  A simple replace will do this, but you want to replace 2 sets, so I'll nest the replace command.

You probably already know this, but the single quote will need doubled in your query so that sql doesn't think your starting a string.

Basically:

```
Replace(Replace([Column], '"', ''), '''', '')
-- here are the targets    ^         ^^
-- replaced with nothing       ^^         ^^
```

So, your final code may be:

```
SELECT
  EmpID,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(EmpName, '"', ''), '''',''),
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CompName, '"', ''), '''','')

FROM
  yourTableName
```